# how to change between '0x604f' and b'\x60\x4f'?

Tags: python, python-3.3

Is there difference between '0x604f' and   b'\x60\x4f' ?
1.how to change  '0x604f' into  b'\x60\x4f'  in python ?
2.how to change  b'\x60\x4f' into   '0x604f' in python ?
I am in python3.3 .

Comment: Hrm, this question needs a more google-able title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `int(s, 0)` to convert a string of the form `0x...` into an integer. The argument `0` in place of an integer base instructs `int` to convert according to the prefix: 0x for base 16, 0o for base 8, 0b for base 2, and no prefix for base 10.

Then, you can use `struct.pack` (from the [`struct module`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/struct.html)) to pack the integer into a bytestring.

Demonstration:

```
>>> struct.pack('>H', int('0x604f', 0))
b'`O'
>>> b'\x60\x4f'
b'`O'
```

And in reverse, use `hex` and `struct.unpack`:

```
>>> hex(struct.unpack('>H', b'\x60\x4f')[0])
'0x604f'
```

Note that the format `>H` means "big-endian, 16-bit number". You can use a different format string for a different number of bytes (`B` for an 8-bit number, `I` for a 32-bit number, `Q` for a 64-bit number).

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.2 you can do it directly using [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) as:

```
>>> int('0x604f', 16).to_bytes(2, 'big')
b'`O'
>>>
```

and the other way around using [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes):

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\x60\x4f', 'big')
24655
>>>
```